# Checking if update was made by ON CASCADE UPDATE and not by any other method

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to know if update on the table was made by ON UPDATE CASCADE and not by any other method?

```
create table systems (system nvarchar(10))
go

create table subsystems (system nvarchar(10), subsystem nvarchar(10))
go

-- adding foreign key with cascade update

create trigger subsystems_utrig
on subsystems
for update
as

if update (system) -- should be checking for cascade update
begin
  -- raiserror ('cascade update not allowed',18,1) rollback transaction
  -- insert something in the log table
  return
end
go

insert into systems (system)
select 'first system'
go

insert into subsystems (system, subsystem)
select system, 'sub' + system
    from systems
go

update systems
    set system = 'new system'
    where system = 'first system'
go
```

So, after update statement, cascade should work and subsystems' update trigger fire.
Any thought on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to *prevent* something from happening that you shouldn't have allowed to get to this point anyway - if you don't want the cascaded update to occur, why have you marked the FK as cascade?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Bad example, agree... But the point when error is raised, any other logic could be implemented. It could leave the trigger, save something to the log table, etc.